# Django CheckboxSelectMultiple not displaying in ModelForm

Tags: django, forms, django-widget, multiplechoicefield

I'm trying to use CheckboxSelectMultiple in a form, instead of the SelectMultiple default. I tried two different ways to make it display as checkboxes, but they both display the default SelectMultiple on my local webpage. Everything else renders correctly ( {{ form.as_table }} ). Would someone point me in the right direction? Thanks,

*Django version 3.0.2*

*Python 3.6.9*

**models.py**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    m2m = models.ManyToManyField('OtherModel', blank=True)

    [...]
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from myapp.models import MyModel

class MyModelModelForm(ModelForm):
    [...]
    # I tried this...
    m2m = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
    
        # or this...
        widgets = {
            'm2m': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        }
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from myapp.models import MyModel

class MyModelCreate(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'MyApp/mymodel_form.html'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not *use* the form you constructed. You simply constructed a `ModelForm`, and then let the `CreateView` create another `ModelForm` since you did not specify a [**`form_class`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_class).

You can thus update the `CreateView`, and work with:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from myapp.models import MyModel
from myapp.forms import MyModelModelForm

class MyModelCreate(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyModelModelForm
    template_name = 'MyApp/mymodel_form.html'
```

Comment: Hey, that did it! Thanks!